# Can i use scanf to choose at which point the string will be modified?

Tags: c, string

Suppose i have something like:

```
char str1[50] ;
```

and i want to use scanf to insert a phrase into the string:

```
scanf("%s",Tstr1) ;
```

but i dont want the string to occupy the position `str1[0]`, just from `str1[1]` forward.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can

```
char str1[50] ;
scanf("%48s",&str1[1]); //or str1 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using:

```
scanf("%s",(str1+1));
```

`(str1+1)` returns the address of the next character byte.